# Xcode interface: how to hide blue line on editor

Tags: xcode, interface

I am trying to hide this blue line that just started showing up on the left side of my editor. When clicked, it has a "Search" and "Discard Changes" option.

[Editor with Blue Line on left side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTNgI.png)

I'm not sure what I did to make it start showing up. I have looked through the View options but can't find anything to hide it. I don't even know what it is called and am having a hard time googling it.

UPDATE:
So I found out that I can click Source Control --> Commit to make the blue line go away... but every time I edit something it comes back. It wasn't like this before. I must have hit some shortcut combination to turn it on. Please help... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Xcode Preferences, go to the "Source Control" tab and you'll see this checkbox:

[image: Show Source Control Changes]

Comment: Thanks Michael. I appreciate the reply and answer, and yes that does hide the blue line. But I believe there is still a different option out there. When I open a different project, that blue line doesn't show up even when the "Text Editing" box is checked... it's only in this one particular project that the blue line shows up.

Comment: That project has a Git repository, and the others don't. You should read a little about Git. It's very helpful, and the basics don't take that long to learn!

Comment: Not helpful, the issue persists